# Search a page for a specific URL and copy first instance to clipboard

Tags: javascript, ios, shortcut

I am trying to set up Shortcut in iOS that searches the current webpage for urls staring with https://rapidgator and then copies the full url of the first instance it finds to the clipboard. I have found a code that does this for magnet links and have changed this line of code

```
const magnetScheme = "magnet:";
```

to tell it look for “https://rapidgator”

```
const magnetScheme = "https://rapidgator";
```

but this then copies all instances of this it finds and not just the first one it finds.

This is the full code I am using that then passes the JavaScript Result to the clipboard.

```
var links= document.querySelectorAll("a");
var magnets = [];

 for (var link of links) 
{
var href = link.getAttribute("href") || "";
const magnetScheme = "magnet:";

if (!href.startsWith(magnetScheme)) 
{
  continue;
}

var magnet = href

// Don't add duplicates
if (magnets.indexOf(magnet) === -1) 
{
    magnets.push(magnet);
}
}

completion(magnets);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This code only finds urls in one sort of element (a). Is that what you want?

Comment: @AHaworth I really don’t know. I have zero knowledge in this field. I want it to search the whole page for rapidgator urls and then pass the first one it finds to the next stage in the iOS shortcut which is copy JavaScript result to clipboard.

Comment: What the code you are using does is find only the urls which are in elements of this form: <a href=“a url”>...</a> This may be enough but you’ll need to look at the generated code in the page you are interested in to see if that would give you what you want or whether there are other instances of urls you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that the given code only looks for urls in anchor elements (see comments) the simple way of returning only the first is to break out of the loop when you have found one:

```
var links= document.querySelectorAll("a");
var magnets = [];

 for (var link of links) 
{
var href = link.getAttribute("href") || "";
const magnetScheme = "magnet:";

if (!href.startsWith(magnetScheme)) 
{
  continue;
}

var magnet = href; // we’ve got one
magnets.push(magnet);// put it into the returnable array
break;// and leave the loop

/* the following code is redundant as we aren’t looking for more than one
// Don't add duplicates
if (magnets.indexOf(magnet) === -1) 
{
    magnets.push(magnet);
}
```

End of redundant code  */
}

```
completion(magnets);
```